# In Auth0 java security api, how do you update app_metadata

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, auth0

I'm using the auth0-spring-security-api and I have a scenario where I need to update the app_metadata for a user when they make a request to an endpoint in my API. I've been looking for any sort of example or even method in the source that could give me a clue on how to do this and I just haven't seen anything. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of searching I found a solution. The answer is essentially that you need to connect to the management API via a http request that you can find in the Auth0 management api examples for various endpoints. I was somewhat hoping that they would have some sort of existing java library to make it easier instead of having to roll my own. I did however find [this github repo](https://github.com/tawawa/auth0-management-api)
that explains what is needed to connect to their API.